# Reading from port, bitconverter wrong value

Tags: c#, encoding, serial-port, bitconverter

I'm using proximity card reader to read card number.
Using producer software, when I read I'm getting this number:

> BF 1C 08 04 01

But using my application this one:

> 3F-1C-08-04-01

Code:

```
void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
            _received += sp.ReadExisting();
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(_received);
            bytes = SubArray(bytes, 5, 5);//to get only that I need
            string s2 = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);


            _received = s2.Replace("-", "");

            string result = SocketSendReceive(host, port);

            _received = "";
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: ASCII only goes up to 127, but 0xBF exceeds that limit. Perhaps that's the problem. What happens if you use `Encoding.Default` instead of `ASCIIEncoding`?

Comment: Result is 01-0D-13-00-01-3F-1C-08-04-01-3F-53-3F, but im taking only 5 from index 5, so it's 3F-1C-08-04-01 - the same wrong value

Comment: Well, maybe there is another topic with this problem, but with every Encoding I'm getting the same (wrong) values.

Comment: So yea, well, still have no idea wha'ts wrong assuming solution from that other topic..